# PHP_CodeSniffer to check for file extensions in a folder

Tags: cakephp, phpcodesniffer

I am using the CakePHP framework, and would like to have PHP_CodeSniffer warn against image files that developers might in a haste, paste into the `app/webroot/css` folder while copying in something, as opposed to moving them into an appropriate folder in `app/webroot/img`.

Is this a bad idea? If not, how do I write a custom sniff to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you would use CS for that as its not code. Look at pre-commit hooks if you are using git.